# $q.all pushing Json header in array when pushing key value

Tags: angularjs

I am developing an application. I have multiple ajax calls and I need to bind all json into single json. I used below code. But when doing it's also appending json response headers, status and others. I need to push only the key values. Can anyone help me out of this ?

My code is below :

```js
$scope.downloadPdf = function () {
    var frequency = $http.get("myapplicationurl" + $stateParams.searchId + "?" + "startDate=" + $stateParams.startDate + "&" + "endDate=" + $stateParams.endDate)//,
    // name = $http.get("../myapplicationurl/" + $stateParams.searchId)
    $q.all([frequency]).then(function (arrayOfResults) {
        angular.forEach(arrayOfResults[0], function (value, key) {
            angular.forEach(value[0], function (data, header) {
                $scope.header.push([header]);
            })
            angular.forEach(value, function (it, header) {
                $scope.columns.push(it);
                console.log("Body : " + $scope.columns);
            })
        })
        console.log("Header : " + $scope.header);
        pdfMake.createPdf({
            header: 'simple text',
            content: [
                {
                    text: 'Fruits and Calories'
                },
                {
                    style: 'demoTable',
                    table: {
                        widths: ['*', '*', '*'],
                        body: [
                            $scope.header,
                // $scope.columns
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            footer: {
                columns: [
                    'Left part',
                    {text: 'Right part', alignment: 'right'}
                ]
            },
            styles: {
                header: {
                    bold: true,
                    color: '#000',
                    fontSize: 11
                },
                demoTable: {
                    color: '#666',
                    fontSize: 10
                }
            }
        }).download('Sample.pdf');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First, not sure why you need to use $q.all(), as you have only 1 promise to wait for.
Second, write a simple .then(function(result) {... }) for your $http call, and inspect the returned object. There you can find out which element you should extract for getting only "key values", as the result object will contain also the request, headers, statuses etc.
I think what you are looking for is on "result.data".